# How to use Control drag in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am just starting off with iOS development. I am trying to add action to a button and it is mentioned on apple developer site that "To Control-drag, press and hold the Control key while you drag from the button to the implementation file in the assistant editor pane."
But am not able to do this. What is control key? How can i do this? When I try to add control drag, entire button is getting dragged and am not able to see any control-drag arrow. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either click and drag with the right mouse button (if you have one), or hold down the Control key while you click and drag with your left (single) mouse button.

By "Control" key, they're referring to the Control key on your keyboard:

[image]

Comment: Note that if you have a two button mouse (or have configured one of Apple's touchpads for 'secondary button' input), you can right-click-drag, too. (If I'm remembering right. I'm on my iPhone right now, and it doesn't have a second button.)