# Xcode way to print "Hello World" when button is clicked in OS X Swift application?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

I'm an experienced Java and Visual Studio developer, but I am just starting out with Swift & Xcode. I am an utter noob, who has never written a line of objective-c. I want to print "Hello World" when I click on the button that I have added in the "Storyboard" view for my application. But I cannot figure out how to get Xcode to insert an event method anywhere in the swift source code files. I’ve read %60 of "The Swift Programming Language", but I don't know any of the cocoa apis yet. Most examples reference objective-c files that do not exist in a Swift application. I also am not using the iOS platform, so I suspect some examples I've pasted (i.e. @IBAction func buttonTapped ) fail because they are not applicable to OS X applications.

I would appreciate a little help :)

Comment: You can't just paste the IBAction, you also have to link it to your button's selector in the Connections Inspector in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks again to Bigman and leonardo-savio-dabus. Future noobs will want to know that the magic starts in the *control-drag* aka *2nd-mouse-button* drag. See [Connecting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14420726/816566)

Comment: You would expect this to be trivially simple. You would be wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to link a button for OSX is the same for iOS

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(button: NSButton)
{
   ...
}
```

One thing to note is here we use NSButton.

In the storyboard, you should see a view controller (a yellow cube).

1. click on this view controller
2. check the right panel and the 3rd icon on the top. Click it
3. You will see "Custom Class" "Class" "Module"
4. In "Class", drop down and choose the view controller class you implemented
5. Make sure you implemented this buttonTap function in the class
6. In the storyboard make sure you see the button
7. hold the control key, click on the button and drag to the yellow cube
8. release your mouse
9. see the buttonTapped function show in the menu popping up
10. choose this function

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid, I need baby steps. So given I have two buttons labeled "Start" and "Stop" in my Main.storyboard, and I have
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(button: NSButton) {
        println("button tapped!")
    }

In the file "ViewController.swift", then what do I do? Thanks!

Comment: In the storyboard, you should see a view controller (a yellow cube).

Comment: In the storyboard, you should see a view controller (a yellow cube). 1. click on this view controller 2. check the right panel and the 3rd icon on the top. Click it 3. You will see "Custom Class" "Class" "Module" 4. In "Class", drop down and choose the view controller class you implemented 5. Make sure you implemented this buttonTap function in the class 6. In the storyboard make sure you see the button 7. hold the control key, click on the button and drag to the yellow cube 8. release your mouse 9. see the buttonTapped function show in the menu popping up 10. choose this function

Comment: Thanks! On my screen, "View Controller" is a blue+white square-in-circle, while the orange cube has the mouseover text ![First Responder](http://hymes.name/xcode_view-controller_abridged.png) . Connecting "First Responder" did not yied the desired results, but "View Controller" did. Yea!

Answer (score 12):

You just need to add a label and a button to your window. Then you need to connect your label outlet to your code.

[image]

You need to connect your button to your viewController also:

[image]

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var strLabel: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func printHello(sender: AnyObject) {
        strLabel.stringValue = "Hello World !!!"
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pictures!  Saved me!